# Way of separating question-based and answer-based reputation?

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to be able to see how much reputations I got from asking questions (i.e. up/down votes on the questions) and from answering questions (up/down votes and the answer-accepted rep bump). I wish there was some UI for that on the profile page.